# React Native AsyncStorage for onboarding screen show only once on first launch

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I want the onboarding screen to show only on the first launch of the App. I've implement the `OnboardScreen` and `AuthScreen`. I've implement `AsyncStorage` with `If Else` statement to check if the user has launched the App for the first time or not. The problem I have is that when the app is closed and then opened again the `OnboardScreen` is shown again.

I'm using React Native Expo to run the application.

App.tsx

```js
import OnboardScreen from "./src/screens/OnboardScreen/OnboardScreen";
import AuthScreen from "./src/screens/AuthScreen/AuthScreen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isFirstTimeLoad, setIsFirstTimeLoad] = useState(false) 
  
  //AsyncStorage
  const checkForFirstTimeLoaded = async () => {
    const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isFirstTimeOpen')
    if(result == null) setIsFirstTimeLoad(true);
    setLoading(false)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    checkForFirstTimeLoaded() 
  }, [])

  if(loading) return null
  
  if(isFirstTimeLoad) return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="OnboardScreen"
            component={OnboardScreen}
            options={{ title: "Onboard", headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AuthScreen"
            component={AuthScreen}
            options={{ title: "Authentication", headerShown: false}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );

    if(!isFirstTimeLoad) return <AuthScreen/>
}
export default App
```

Onboard.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import Onboarding from "react-native-onboarding-swiper";

const Skip = ({...props}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "#F4F4F4", 
      borderRadius: 10, 
      width: 90, 
      height: 40,
      padding: 5,
      alignItems: "center", 
      left: 25}}
    {...props}
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Skip</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

const Next = ({...props}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "#258671", 
      borderRadius: 10, 
      width: 90, 
      height: 40,
      padding: 5, 
      alignItems: "center", 
      right: 25}}
    {...props} 
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Next</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

const Done = ({...props}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "#258671", 
      borderRadius: 10, 
      width: 90, 
      height: 40,
      padding: 5, 
      alignItems: "center", 
      right: 25}}
    {...props} 
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Done</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Dots = ({selected}) => {
  let backgroundColor;

  backgroundColor = selected ? "rgba(37, 134, 113, 1)" : "rgba(185, 185, 185, 1)"

  return (
    <View 
      style={{
        width: 6,
        height: 6,
        borderRadius: 3,
        marginHorizontal: 3,
        backgroundColor
      }}
    />
  );
}

const OnboardScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Onboarding
        SkipButtonComponent={Skip}
        NextButtonComponent={Next}
        DoneButtonComponent={Done}
        DotComponent={Dots}
        onSkip={() => navigation.replace("AuthScreen")}
        onDone={() => navigation.navigate("AuthScreen")}
        titleStyles={{ color: 'blue' }}
        pages={[
          {
            backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
            image: <Image source={require('../../assets/images/onboard-5.png')} />,
            title: 'A.I. Powered',
            subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
            image: <Image source={require('../../assets/images/onboard-5.png')} />,
            title: 'Onboarding 2',
            subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
            image: <Image source={require('../../assets/images/onboard-5.png')} />,
            title: 'Onboarding 3',
            subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
          },
          {
            backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
            image: <Image source={require('../../assets/images/onboard-5.png')} />,
            title: 'Onboarding 4',
            subtitle: 'Done with React Native Onboarding Swiper',
          },
        ]}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default OnboardScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `isFirstTimeOpen` to false after onboarding is shown. Note that Async Storage can only store string data.

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('isFirstTimeOpen', 'false')
```